# Problems xerces, xml-apis JDK1.4 to JDK1.7

Tags: java, xml, weblogic, xerces

First of all sorry if there is something like that but i haven´t found it, or at least i haven´t found a solution to my problem

I'm upgrading a project developed in `jdk4` using libraries such as xml-apis, xerces or xercesImpl managed by Maven.

Now the new version is developed with `jdk7`. Here is when troubles comes.
When I pack the application everything it´s ok.
If I use Tomcat it´s ok as well, but when I access to it by Weblogic the log says:

```
Class org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$AttributesProxy does not implement 
the requested interface org.xml.sax.Attributes
```

I´ve tried most of things but I don´t know how to solve it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried a [google search](https://www.google.de/search?q=Class+org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser%24AttributesProxy+does+not+implement+the+requested+interface+org.xml.sax.Attributes&oq=Class+org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser%24AttributesProxy+does+not+implement+the+requested+interface+org.xml.sax.Attributes&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) ?

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason I'm asking here. I don't like people waste time for free. Any help it´s welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in `xml-apis` has been included in the core Java class library since Java 5, so you should exclude any transitive dependencies on `xml-apis` in your pom. The error message you're seeing tends to occur when you have different classloaders in the mix, with the xerces classes binding to interfaces from xml-apis but other code trying to cast them to the same interface as defined by rt.jar.

Comment: The problem is the error appears once i have removed the xml-apis dependencies.

Comment: @JavierPiquerasPascual Check your `dependency:tree` - are you sure they're completely gone?  Or is there some other copy of the XML APIs somewhere else in weblogic?

Comment: I have not found any xml-apis.jar.
I'm making a mess of this, I don't know if i only have to remove this .jar or everything around Xerces because rt.jar(JDK+1.5) has everything in it.

Comment: At the end... besides removing these libraries I have had to add rt.jar despite having jdk7 because the war didn't include it.
Thanksss!